# Display default access privileges for relations, sequences and functions in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

After altering the default privileges on a Postgres database object, how can you view them?

For instance, if you grant all privileges to `role_name` for all tables created in the schema `schema_name`:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_name GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO role_name;
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Using a SQL query

```
SELECT 
  nspname,         -- schema name
  defaclobjtype,   -- object type
  defaclacl        -- default access privileges
FROM pg_default_acl a JOIN pg_namespace b ON a.defaclnamespace=b.oid;
```

Where the value of `defaclobjtype` is [r = relation (table, view), S = sequence, f = function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-default-acl.html).

These access privileges are only for newly created objects within the schema namespace.

Comment: If you get zero results with the query above, try it without the join on pg_namespace. That's the query I used until I found out about \ddp.

Comment: @Zyphrax Indeed, if you run psql with `-E`, you can see that `\ddp` uses a LEFT JOIN there.

Comment: Worked for me! Event found a bad/incorrectly assigned grant to a user.

Comment: and the "result" appears in col defaclacl, in a form like "{<role>=arwdDxt/<owner>}" , which says the role will be granted permissions arwdDxt for objects created by owner.

Answer (score 56):

### Using the psql(1) interactive terminal

There is another way, at least in recent Postgres versions.
Use the `\ddp` command

```
               Default access privileges
     Owner      | Schema |   Type   | Access privileges 
----------------+--------+----------+-------------------
 role_x         |        | function | =X/role_x
 role_x         |        | sequence | 
 role_x         |        | table    | 
 role_x         |        | type     | =U/role_x
```

Read more about it under the Notes section here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: Sidenote: default privileges are sometimes difficult to remove. In my case I was trying to drop a role, so I first transfered the ownership with REASSIGN OWNED and then dropped things like the default privileges with DROP OWNED.

Comment: @Madeo you may not have created any access privileges. I just ran `\ddp` on a new database created with Postgresql 12.5 and it returns *0 rows*.

Comment: @Madeo you should only get rows with this if you actually executed "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES" on an object

Answer (score 2):

If you join `pg_default_acl` to `pg_namespace` you will only list default privileges that are granted using in the schema.

Comment: pg_default_act->pg_default_acl